# HttpOnly for request cookies

Tags: security, session-cookies, owasp, hdiv

Is there a way of setting a **request** cookie **[httpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)**? If not why can't we set it? I've set the response cookies to **[httpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)** using weblogx.xml/weblogic server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not possible.

Cookies are *set* in a HTTP response, and are *read* from a HTTP request. You can only set flags when cookies are created, so they can only be set in the response when using HTTP so it would not make sense to set HttpOnly on a request cookie.

Comment: I knew this, but I wanted to get a confirmation. Thanks very much and +1.